# What direction should I extend my menu?

Tags: menu

I am just making a website and don't know which direction I should extend my menu for best user experience and most intuitive feel.

The buttons to open the menu are in the top, right corner. I have to decide wether to extend the menu to the left or to the right of the button.

To the right

[image: Ext. right]

To the left.

[image: Ext. left]

The extension to the left looks better for me. It's more comfortable to move the cursor *into* the webpage.

Comment: I think this is one case where you can trust that the reason every other OS and website (of which I'm aware) does something a particular way is because it's more intuitive and user-friendly. Those extend menus in the locale's text direction (i.e. to the right) unless forced by space constraints to do something else.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the "general case" (not at the right-hand edge), left-aligning the drop-down and extending to the right (as in the first example) looks best (to me), especially since "the control" (in my mind, and I suspect most users') is the combination of the icon and the label "*Deutsch*"<sup>**1**</sup> and so the drop-down sits "under" the (combined) control most neatly.

If you *are* near the right-hand edge of the screen -- and left-aligning would take you off the edge of the screen -- then I would put the right-hand edge of the drop-down just inside the edge of the screen (similar to the right-hand edge in the first image) and extend the drop-down as far to the left as needed to display the options (so as much of it as possible is "under" the menu-bar control). Although in the example shown none of the options are long enough to require this, if an option *was* long-enough, the left-hand edge might be as shown in the second image.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> And, ideally, tapping/clicking on either part should activate the drop-down.

Comment: @ThomasMoors: Why doesn't this suggestion work for longer names?

Comment: @ThomasMoors It would only not work if the name is too long to fit on the screen. If there's enough room to the right, use left-alignment. If that would not fit, fix the right-hand edge and extend to the left sufficiently to contain the string.

Comment: @TripeHound Fair point!

Answer (score 2):

Use the extension to the left. There's no room to the right when you have to use longer labels (like 'English (United States)', for example).

Comment: In this case, it should go as far to the right as it can, and then expand to the left.

Comment: Or you could use two lines